# Is EFS a substitute of HDFS for distributed storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hdfs, amazon-efs

Our business requirement is to read from millions of files and process those parallelly (later index those in ES). This is a one time operation and after processing those we won't read those million files again. Now, we want to distribute the file storage and at the same time ensure data retention. I did some research and made the list

1. EBS: The data is retained even after EC2 instance is shut down. It is accessible from a single EC2 instance from our AWS region. It will be useful if we split the data on our own and provide it to different EC2 instances. It offers redundancy and encryption security. Easy to scale. We can use it if we divide the chunks manually and provide those to the different servers we have.
2. EFS: It allows us to mount the FS across multiple regions and instances (accessible from multiple EC2 instances). Since EFS is a managed service, we don’t have to worry about maintaining and deploying the FS
3. S3: Not limited to access from EC2 but S3 is not a file system
4. HDFS: Extremely good at scale but is only performant with double or triple replication. Scaling down HDFS is painful and buggy. "It also lacks encryption at storage and network levels. It has also been connected to various controversies because cybercriminals can easily exploit the frameworks that are built on Java." Not sure how big of a concern this is considering our servers are pretty secure.
5. Problem with small files in Hadoop, explained in https://data-flair.training/forums/topic/what-is-small-file-problem-in-hadoop/ Considering most of the files we receive are less then 1 MB; this can cause memory issues if we go beyond a certain number. So it will not give us the performance we think it should.

My confusion is in HDFS:
I went through a lot of resources that talk about "S3" vs "HDFS" and surprisingly there are no clear resources on "EFS" vs "HDFS" which confuses me in understanding if they are really a substitute for each other or are complementary.

1. For example, one question I found was "Has anyone tried using AWS EFS mounts as yarn scratch and HDFS directories?" -> what does it mean to have EFS mount as HDFS directory?
2. "Using EBS volumes for HDFS prevents data locality" - What does it mean to use "EBS volume" for HDFS?
3. What does it mean to run "HDFS in the cloud"?

References

- https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/31/top-5-reasons-for-choosing-s3-over-hdfs.html
- https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/hdfs-vs-cloud-storage-pros-cons-and-migration-tips
- https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/big-data/top-pros-and-cons-of-hadoop
- https://data-flair.training/blogs/13-limitations-of-hadoop/

Comment: Where are those millions of files currently located? Since they only need to be accessed once, it would be a shame to move them to a new location just for a one-off use. It would be better to use them where they are currently located (if possible).

Comment: We may have hundreds of processes reading from this huge data, we require fast access.

Comment: Where are those millions of files currently located?

Comment: on just one server @JohnRotenstein

Comment: It's rather difficult to recommend a storage layer without knowing how the data will be processed. If it will be processed on Hadoop, then you will want it in HDFS or S3. If using HDFS, there's no benefit to using replication if the file is only being accessed once. If the server currently containing the data is part of the existing cluster, then just use HDFS. If it is outside the cluster, then it's probably easier to use S3. But, I can't say for sure without knowing your setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are possibilities by any kind of storage but as your situation is a one time scenario you need a choice with respect to

1. Cost optimized
2. well Performed
3. Secure

I can not answer to all your questions but concerning your use case I consider you use reach the data from EC2 instance and if you had mentioned the producing and processing of these files and the size of each file approximately maybe I could help you better.

Considerations:

1. EBS has a provisioned or limited Throughput and force you to provision and remove the data after treatment. FYI: you can set retention policy of EBS volume to be deleted by EC2 termination but not on shutdown.

If you need really the fastest way and don't care about costs EBS is a good idea with a good provisioning as you are charged by their life and storage.

2. EFS is a NAS storage and also needs the data be removed after treatment.
3. HDFS  is a distributed file system and is the best choice for petabyte and distributed file systems but is not used as a one shot solution, you need installation and configuration.
4. I propose you personally the S3 as you does not have a limited throughput and using VPC endpoint you can achieve up to 25 Gbps, alternatively you can use the S3 life cycle policies to remove your data automatically based on tags or after 1 up to 356 days or archive them if needed.